# AngularFire Firebase error with Internet Explorer 8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, firebase, angularfire

My code works perfect in all modern browsers, but unfortunately IE 8 is still the primary browser in my industry. IE 8 is not rendering and IE8 Developer Tools is reporting "Object doesn't support this property or method" "firebase.js, line 1 character 28". I am using IE 8.0.6001.18702 on Windows XP Pro SP 3. Here is my complete code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" id="ng-app" ng-app="testApp">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <script src="json2.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.5.0/angularfire.js"></script>

</head>

<body id="ng-app" ng-app="" data-ng-controller="mainController">

<h1>AngularFire Test</h1>

<div ng-repeat="record in records">
    <div>
        {{record.apparentTemperature}} {{record.time}}
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var testApp = angular.module('testApp',['firebase']);

    testApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope','$firebase',function($scope, $firebase){
        $scope.records = [];
        var ref = new Firebase('https://publicdata-weather.firebaseio.com/austin/hourly/data');
        $scope.records = $firebase(ref);
    }]);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This should work fine in IE8 - are there any other libraries that you are including that might have modified Object.prototype?

Comment: Scratch that, seems like AngularFire is using indexOf() that isn't supported by IE8. We'll fix this shortly: https://github.com/firebase/angularFire/issues/196

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I'll be waiting for the fix.

Comment: after you told me that the problem is indexOf() I added the following code to the top of my <head> section and now everything works in IE 8 and all modern browsers

Comment: <!--[if lte IE 8]>
 <script>
   if (!Array.prototype.indexOf)
   {
     Array.prototype.indexOf = function(elt /*, from*/)
     {
       var len = this.length >>> 0;
       var from = Number(arguments[1]) || 0;
       from = (from < 0)
       ? Math.ceil(from)
       : Math.floor(from);
       if (from < 0)
         from += len;
       for (; from < len; from++)
       {
         if (from in this &&
             this[from] === elt)
           return from;
       }
       return -1;
     };
   }
  </script>
<![endif]-->